# Moving command buttons using ribbon workbench 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to rearrange standard buttons using the ribbon workbench. It's the activity entity, command bar. When I try to switch phonecall and appointment (or any button in that group, it says 'There isn't any space for this control in the layout section...'. I would think it would just move the other buttons down but it doesn't appear to be the case. I tried 'customize button' and 'customize group'. Do I need to do it in the xml instead?

Answer (score 0):

The activity ribbon layout sections are different to most sections in that they have named template locations for buttons. You will need right click -> Customise button on each of the buttons you want to change position (phonecall and appointment) and edit the 'Template Alias' property to swap them over. So for example change c4 to c3 and c3 to c4 to swap the phonecall and appointment around.

Comment: If I make the changes in RW, publish and re-open RW, it looks like the changes are there, but when I navigate to Activities, it has the standard command bar. (tried a couple machines and browsers). The solution that I opened in RW only has the activitypointer entity. Is there more to do other than manipulate the Cx template alias?